# reading multiple lines of different data types using python

Tags: python

I have an input where the first line is a string and the next line contains three integers:

```
StackOverflow

1 2 3
```

I have to store the string from the first line to a separate variable and the  3 integers in separate variables. The input is comming from`stdin`.

I tried to use `sys.stdin.read()` but it reads the entire input as one entity. How to split it to separate variables?

Comment: Are you familiar with the built-in [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function?

Comment: Please update the question to show the code you’ve written so far to solve the issue.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes it answers my question. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `readline()` it helps in reading input per line.

```
import sys
string_inp=sys.stdin.readline()
a,b,c=map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
print(string_inp)
print(a,b,c)
```

This way, you'll get integers in 3 different variables and string in another.

use input as:

```
StackOverflow
1 2 3
```

Comment: why not use `input()`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo you can definately use ```input()``` but since OP tried using ```sys.stdin.read()```, I am only trying to point out how a small change could have fixed his problem.

Comment: Oh true, I didn't notice OP said he is using that. In that case that's a good correction but I would still mention about using `input()` as this is the idiomatic way of getting user input...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ip = input().split()

text = ip[0]
num1, num2, num3 = (int(x) for x in ip[1:])

print(text, num1, num2, num3)
```